# How do nested vertical margin collapses work?

Tags: css

I am having a hard time grasping the concept of vertical margins collapsing in nested elements. I came an article at http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing explaining how it works however am confused by its explanation. So in its example it cites that there are 2 elements as follows

```
<div style="margin-top:10px">
<div style="margin-top:20px">
A
</div>
</div>
```

Seeing that the inner div has a margin of 20px, that is what will be applied for the entire block of code. What confuses me is everything after that and not yet looking about issues with Internet Explorer 7. Would someone be able to explain it for a complete newbie to CSS in a simplified manner?

Comment: You mean the bit with the paragraph in the blue div?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can explain it any better than that article already does. Maybe with some beautifully drawn pictures?

Comment: @BoltClock - Everything under `Nested margins` apart from what I stated about the inner block taking precedence.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two-ish rules to remember:

1. If margins touch, they collapse.
2. *Nested* items "snuggle" if *only* margin separates them.
3. Elements outside the "Flow" behave differently.  That is, this behavior does not apply the same to floated, or position:fixed, or position:absolute elements.

So for this HTML (nested divs) :

```
<div id="outer"> 
    <div id="inner">
        A
    </div>
</div>
```

and this initial CSS:

```
#outer {
    margin-top:10px;
    background:blue;
    height: 100px;
}
#inner {
    margin-top:20px;
    background:red;
    height: 33%;   
    width: 33%;
}
```

The margin collapses to the *max* of the touching margins and the nested div "snuggles" to the start of the container, like so:  ([See it at jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/cF5RB/))
[image: Nested margin collapse]

But, the moment the two margins are separated -- by a border or by preceding content in the container, for example -- the margins no longer touch, so they no longer collapse.

EG, just a little, non-breaking white-space , like so:

```
<div id="outer">&nbsp;
    <div id="inner">
        A
    </div>
</div>
```

kills the collapse : ([See that at jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/cF5RB/1/))
[image: Nested margin doesn't collapse]

Using a border, instead of leading text : ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cF5RB/3/))
[image: no-collapse, border]

Comment: Thanks. When you say `preceding content in the container` what do you mean exactly? I also take it that if the preceding container e.g. the parent div in a nested div as in the example below has a border or padding, it also `breaks` the vertical collapse. Is that right?

`<div id="parent"><div id="child1">content</div><div id="child2">content</div>`

Comment: By "preceding content" I meant anything (besides collapsing whitespace) that was inside `div#outer` and *before* `div#inner`.  In the example, I used `&nbsp;` but text or another node would do as well.  And yes, if `div#outer` has a border or padding, it separates the margins, breaking the collapse.  See the updated answer.

Comment: When you say `collapsing whitespace` do you mean the height given to an element e.g. if I define the `font-size` to be 1em the height or whitespace between the elements is 1em?

Comment: No, most whitespace at the beginning or end of an element *collapses* and is not seen.  That is: the browser will render `<p>     Hello       </p>` the same as `<p>Hello</p>`.  Ditto for `<p> \n \r \t Hello</p>`.   Only special, *non-breaking* whitespace is exempted from this collapse.

Comment: Ah right. Do you have examples of special non-breaking whitespace?

Comment: The most common one is the [`&nbsp;` entity](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp).  You can also type this as character-code 160. (On Windows, hold down the `Alt` key and then press `0160` with the numeric keypad.)

Answer (score 6):

A diagram may help:

[image: Illustration of collapsing margins for nested divs]

In case it wasn't obvious: blue = outer div, red = inner div; I've drawn them with constant height and horizontal positioning.  You can work out what happens if the height is fitted to the contents etc.

The "Before collapsing" column shows what you get if the margins aren't considered adjacent, e.g. if you draw the border of the blue/outer div; but if there is no border, then you get the "After collapsing" column.  The top row switches the two margins around from the example, because I think the behaviour in this case is more intuitive; the bottom one shows the example at howtocreate and is consistent with the top row.

Comment: Thanks Brian. A few questions. When you say that you have drawn them with a constant height and horizontal positioning, what do you mean exactly? When you also say not adjacent what does that mean exactly? My understanding is adjacent equals to what occurs in the normal flow of the document i.e. you have one element above another with no styling whateverso.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Their heights and horizontal positioning have not changed in the before and after phases; you'll notice they're the same size, just moved up/down the vertical axis. Not adjacent/adjoining means they're not touching each other.

Comment: @BoltClock - I take that the reason they have not changed is because the height is set to `auto`. Is that right? If that is the case why does height attribute i.e. `height: 10px` not affect it any way? It seems that the only attributes to affect height are the padding and border attributes.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: It's because the box model states that height only consists of `height`, it does not take margins, border or padding into account.

Comment: @BoltClock - What do you mean by `It's because the box model states that height only consists of height`?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - It looks like you've got most of your questions answered already, but to make sure: constant height means setting `height: 100px` (if you don't do this then divs will naturally just resize their height according to the text and other elements in them).  This just explains the diagrams, the margins still behave the same way. (The height property is exclusive of margins).

You can achieve the horizontal positioning shown either by putting padding on the outer div or a left margin on the inner div, neither way will affect how the vertical margins work.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey -
Adjacent margins means that if you consider the vertical space, and look at where the margins would be before collapsing, then the margin of the outside div touches the margin of the inside div.  If there is some content in the outside div before the inner div, or there is padding, or there is a border, then the two margins will not be considered adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

> Two-ish rules to remember:
>
> If margins touch, they collapse. Nested items "snuggle" if only margin separates them. Elements outside the "Flow" behave differently. That is, this behavior does not apply the same to floated, or position:fixed, or position:absolute elements.

Brock Adams is correct, but I also wanted to add that "overflow:hidden" can also prevent nested margins from collapsing.